# Neo4j Query - Find all nodes which satisfy a property condition and have relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query which runs successfully:

`match (n:A {tag_no:"N2203"})<-[:rel_a]-(v:B)-[:rel_b]->(r)<-[:rel_c]-(n) WHERE  (v.invoice_date>="2012-08-01" AND v.invoice_date<"2016-02-01") with v, collect(r) as rs where all (x in rs where x.date<"2016-08-01") return count(v) as count;`

I need to further filter this query.

I need to related `r nodes with max(r.date) for each v`, and find out how many of those nodes have a relationship with another node of type `D`

I'm trying this query, it throws a syntax error

`match (n:A {tag_no:"N2203"})<-[:rel_a]-(v:B)-[:rel_b]->(r)<-[:rel_c]-(n) WHERE  (v.invoice_date>="2012-08-01" AND v.invoice_date<"2016-02-01") with v, max(r.date) as date collect(r) as rs where (all (x in rs where x.date<"2016-08-01") AND filter(x in rs where x.date=date)[0]<-[:rel_c]-(d:D)) return count(v) as count;`

I also tried many other combinations, but all throw some syntax error. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Your queries would benefit from formatting, which would make debuggind easier. Please use 4 spaces of indentation (instead of triple backticks) and also use more whitespaces in the query. I created and example at https://gist.github.com/szarnyasg/8b53983b5ade8a31e4410f8f48ee3653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that query parser cannot now if `filter(x in rs where x.date=date)[0]` really is a node, so this is not allowed in the syntax. Fortunately, it's possible to work around this at the cost of some verbosity:

- Use another `WITH` clause to introduce an alias (`n`) to the node variable. That will allow you to use the `WHERE <pattern>` syntax.
- Also, you cannot introduce new variables in the `WHERE` clause, so just use `(:D)` instead of `(d:D)`.

So the query will look like this (obviously, I have not tested it):

```
MATCH (n:A {tag_no:"N2203"})<-[:rel_a]-(v:B)-[:rel_b]->(r)<-[:rel_c]-(n)
WHERE v.invoice_date>="2012-08-01"
  AND v.invoice_date<"2016-02-01"
WITH
  v,
  max(r.date) AS date,
  collect(r) AS rs
WHERE all(x IN rs WHERE x.date<"2016-08-01")
WITH filter(x in rs where x.date=date)[0] AS n, v
WHERE (n)<-[:rel_c]-(:D)
RETURN count(v) AS count;
```